# Problem formulating a hypothesis test for the mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose that I would like to support the following hypothesis:

h = The average weight of people in New York is 70kg.

If I take h to be the null hypothesis then I can only reject it (I assume that failing to reject h will not support h).

So, how can I formulate a hypothesis test for supporting h?

Comment: What tolerance do you have for being “close enough” to $70?$ For instance, is $71$ close enough? Is $80$ close enough? Is $70.0001$ close enough?

Comment: My question in general is to support a claim about the mean of a population. From your answer I understand that if I specify a tolerance level then it can be done, am I right? If so, I would appreciate if you show how can it be done. For this particular case we can assume that 71 is close enough.

Comment: Then the term you want to investigate is *equivalence testing*. The easiest approach is [two one-sided tests: TOST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extended comment:* Maybe you really want a confidence interval for the mean $\mu$ of the population of weights of people (young adults?) in NYC.

For example, for *normally distributed* weights (technically *masses*) with $\mu=70$kg, $\sigma=7$kg and a sample of size $n=1000,$ R code `set.seed(515); t.test(rnorm(1000, 70, 7))$conf.int` gives 95% CI $(69.635, 70.495)$ for $\mu.$ [To the nearest kg, both endpoints round to $70.]$

```
set.seed(515)
x = rnorm(1000, 70, 7)
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 69.63495 70.49523
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  47.42   65.27   70.14   70.07   74.86   92.15 

 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

A major difficulty with your question may be to specify
what sub-population of New Yorkers you have in mind.
The actual distribution of all adults in the city is likely
an intricate mixture of diverse normal and gamma distributed populations, and there is no reason to believe
that the overall distribution of their weights is well-modeled
as normal.

*Addendum:* Very roughly, you might decide to use the distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=8,\mathrm{rate}=8/70)$ as a model
for the population, obtaining the sample `y` of size 1000
below. The population mean is $\mu = 70$ and the sample mean is $\bar Y = 69.68.$

```
set.seed(2022)
y = rgamma(1000, 8, 8/70)
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  19.98   52.19   66.53   69.68   84.67  167.10 
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Then a 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI for $\mu,$ based on data `y`
is $(68.09, 71.14),$ so it seems that the data are
consistent with $\mu = 70.$

```
a.obs = mean(y)
d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(y,1000,rep=T))-a.obs)
UL = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
a.obs - UL
   97.5%     2.5% 
68.09183 71.13845
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, later I also realized that my problem is an estimation problem not about hypothesis testing. But it is interesting to think about the relationship between estimation and hypothesis testing, they seem to be complementary.